# Duplicate contacts issue when retrieving contacts

Tags: android, duplicates, contacts

I just want to invite friends to my application so that they can use the application too. For this i get all the contacts but the problem is contacts are repeating. Some contacts are showing 2 times and some are 3 and 4 times. I think i should a query "group by" so that no duplicates will be shown but I am confused where to put that query.
Here is my code:

```
private ArrayList<String> conNames;
private ArrayList<String> conNumbers;
private Cursor crContacts;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.invite);
    conNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    conNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    crContacts = ContactHelper.getContactCursor(getContentResolver(), "");
    crContacts.moveToFirst();

    while (!crContacts.isAfterLast()) {
        conNames.add(crContacts.getString(1));
        conNumbers.add(crContacts.getString(2));
        crContacts.moveToNext();
    }

    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            R.id.tvNameMain, conNames));

}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> conNames) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, conNames);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = setList(position, parent);
        return row;
    }

    private View setList(int position, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View row = inf.inflate(R.layout.liststyle, parent, false);

        TextView tvName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNameMain);
        final TextView tvNumber = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNumberMain);
    tvName.setText(conNames.get(position));
        tvNumber.setText(conNumbers.get(position));
        return row;
    }
}
```

Guide me what to do avoid duplicate contacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arslan Ali

If you don't want duplicates in a Collection, you should consider using `HashMap`. It does not allow duplicate keys however it allows to have duplicate values. So since your fetching the `contacts name` and `number`. Number will always be unique so make number your key and name as your value.

so in your case

```
Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

while (!crContacts.isAfterLast()) {
        hm.put(crContacts.getString(2),crContacts.getString(1));
        crContacts.moveToNext();
}
```

So this way you will never have repetitive contacts. Now iterate through you `HashMap` and then push your key value to `conNumbers` and name value to `conNames`

```
for (String key : hm.keySet()) {
   conNames.add(key);
   conNumbers.add(hm.get(key));
}
```

And you got your unique Arraylist.

Comment: Ok sir i got you, let me try this

Comment: Works like a charm. Thankyou :)

Comment: @ArslanAli Welcome brother

Comment: Although the problem is solved but now contacts are not displaying in alphabetic order. Why is that so?

Comment: @ArslanAli its because HashMap never add elements in sorted order in your case once you got ArrayList just sort it using java inbuilt sort() function

Comment: Ok sir i got it :)